# A href Link automaticaly moves to top left

Tags: html, css, background

I started creating a simple page with a background and a link to my homepage. I formated the text with css:

```
h1{
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center !important;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

so the text stays in the middle of the page and the page is formated like this:

```
.box1{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(pics/test.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: table;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

So the problem is when i use a simple h1 the text stays in the middle but when I set it in a link to my index. It moves to the top left corner like it isnt formated. I assume it doesnt see my css configuration. In html it looks like this:

```
    <div class="box1">
      <h1>Test Site</h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you include the linking bit in your code so we can see exactly how you have set it up. Also making your code into a runnable snippet makes it easier to help see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Having said that you may like to investigate CSS flex and grid to help with positioning.

Comment: Did you apply the same styling to the anchor tag as with the h1?

Comment: @abraham_html completely frogot that. Thank you it worked.

Comment: Make sure to put the <a> tags inside the <h1> tags, like so: `<h1><a>Test Site</a></h1>` If you wrap the <h1> tags in <a> tags, you'll end up with illegal HTML code, which might be the cause of your issue.

Comment: @Thomas, do you have a reference for this? I cannot find one and the W3 validator is fine with an h1 inside an anchor element.

Comment: @A Haworth Thanks for drawing my attention to this. To be honest, I didn't verify this but tested it in a fiddle and it had some unexpected behavior. But I verified now and you seem to be right. There's no rule preventing us from wrapping <h1> tags with <a> tags, so my bad. [Here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20446/anchor-tag-inside-h1-or-h1-inside-anchor-tag-which-is-better)'s an interesting discussion on the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the styling from the h1 to a.

```
a{
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center !important;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

and html:

```
    <div class="box1">
      <a href="index.php">Homepage</a>
    </div>
```